# ORB only after 1st 4 candles are within range of 1st candle in pine

Tags: pine-script

I want to write a condition wherein, if on a 15min chart (for example), if the 2nd, 3rd and 4th candle are within the Opening Range made by the 1st 15min candle, then after the 5th candle if any candle breaks out of the range, a buy (upside break) or a sell (downside break) would be triggered.

I have the code for the Opening Range but need to include this criteria.

```
//@version=4

study(title="ORB Indicator", shorttitle="ORB", overlay=true)

//User Input
showHistoricalORB = input(false, title="Show historical ORB", 
type=input.bool)
showAvg = input(false, title="Show average", type=input.bool)
orbTimeFrame = input("15", title="ORB timeframe", type=input.resolution)
sessSpec = input("0915-1530", title="Session time", type=input.session)

// Defaults
// Colors
aColor = color.gray
rColor = color.red
sColor = color.green

// Line style & Transparency
lStyle = plot.style_line
lTransp = 35

// Get High & Low
getSeries(_e, _timeFrame) => security(syminfo.tickerid, _timeFrame, _e, 
lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) 

is_newbar(res, sess) =>
    t = time(res, sess)
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

newbar = is_newbar("375", "0915-1530")

var float orbH = na
var float orbL = na
if newbar
    orbH := getSeries(high[0], orbTimeFrame)
    orbL := getSeries(low[0], orbTimeFrame)

orbA = (orbH + orbL)/2

// Today's Session Start timestamp
y = year(timenow)
m = month(timenow)
d = dayofmonth(timenow)

// Start & End time for Today
start = timestamp(y, m, d, 09, 15)
end = start + 86400000

// Plot only if session started
isToday = timenow > start

// Plot selected timeframe's High, Low & Avg
// Plot lines
if isToday
    _h = line.new(start, orbH, end, orbH, xloc.bar_time, 
color=color.new(rColor, lTransp))
    line.delete(_h[1])
    _l = line.new(start, orbL, end, orbL, xloc.bar_time, 
color=color.new(sColor, lTransp))
    line.delete(_l[1])
    if showAvg
        _a = line.new(start, orbA, end, orbA, xloc.bar_time, 
color=color.new(aColor, lTransp))
        line.delete(_a[1])

// Plot labels
if isToday
    l_h = label.new(start, orbH, text="High", xloc=xloc.bar_time, 
textcolor=rColor, style=label.style_none)
    label.delete(l_h[1])
    l_l = label.new(start, orbL, text="Low", xloc=xloc.bar_time, 
textcolor=sColor, style=label.style_none)
    label.delete(l_l[1])
    if showAvg
        l_a = label.new(start, orbA, text="Avg", xloc=xloc.bar_time, 
textcolor=aColor, style=label.style_none)
        label.delete(l_a[1])


plot(showHistoricalORB ? orbH : na, title=' High', color=rColor, 
transp=lTransp)
plot(showHistoricalORB ? orbL : na, title=' Low', color=sColor, 
transp=lTransp)
plot(showHistoricalORB ? showAvg ? orbA : na : na, title=' Avg', 
color=aColor, transp=lTransp)


// Display Buy & Sell signal
plotSignals = false
if showHistoricalORB
    plotSignals := true
else
    if year(time) == year(timenow) and month(timenow) == month(time) and 
dayofmonth(time) == dayofmonth(timenow) 
        plotSignals := true


//This is the point where i run into the problem of finding out if the 
2nd, 3rd, 4th bars are within the opening range of the 1st 15min bar
//After the 5th bar onwards, any bar if breaks the range, a buy or sell is 
triggered

//n_bar = bar_index

//Calc_candle(oH, oL, a)=>
//    for n_bar = 1 to barstate.islast by 1
//        var orb_break_up = 0
//        var orb_break_dn = 0
//        orb_break_up := close > oH ? 1 : na
//        orb_break_dn := close < oL ? 1 : na
//        [orb_break_up, orb_break_dn]

//[o1, o2] = Calc_candle(orbH, orbL, x)
//plotshape(plotSignals and o1 ? crossover(close, orbH) : na, 
style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.lime, 
text="Buy", textcolor=color.lime)
//plotshape(plotSignals and o2 ? crossover(orbL, close) : na, 
style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, 
text="Sell", textcolor=color.red)
```

Comment: Any attempts you can supply code of?

Comment: sure...where do i send it?

Comment: where do i send it?

Comment: You can edit your question.

Comment: just posted the code above...pls advise...thx.

Answer (score 1):

See comments in code. You were using future data in your `security()` calls and in any case a `security()` call was not needed if you want the chart's opening bar values:

```
//@version=4

study(title="ORB Indicator", shorttitle="ORB", overlay=true)

//User Input
showHistoricalORB = input(true, title="Show historical ORB", type=input.bool)
showAvg = input(false, title="Show average", type=input.bool)
sessSpec = input("0915-1530", title="Session time", type=input.session)

// Defaults
// Colors
aColor = color.gray
rColor = color.red
sColor = color.green

// Line style & Transparency
lStyle = plot.style_line
lTransp = 35

is_newbar(res, sess) =>
    t = time(res, sess)
    (na(t[1]) and not na(t)) or t[1] < t

newbar = is_newbar("D", "0915-1530")

var float orbH = na
var float orbL = na
var bars234InRange = false
var barNo = 0
// We're evaluating the condition on each bar because that's what needed for it to calculate correctly,
//  but only use its result when we are on bar 4.
last3BarsInRange = sum(min(open, close) > orbL and max(open, close) < orbH ? 1 : 0, 3) == 3
if newbar
    orbH := high
    orbL := low
    bars234InRange := false
    barNo := 1
else
    barNo := barNo + 1
    if barNo == 4
        // Bar 4 reached; check if bars 2,3 and 4 are within the range of the first.
        bars234InRange := last3BarsInRange

orbA = (orbH + orbL)/2

// Today's Session Start timestamp
y = year(timenow)
m = month(timenow)
d = dayofmonth(timenow)

// Start & End time for Today
start = timestamp(y, m, d, 09, 15)
end = start + 86400000

// Plot only if session started
isToday = timenow > start

// Plot selected timeframe's High, Low & Avg
// Plot lines
if isToday
    _h = line.new(start, orbH, end, orbH, xloc.bar_time, color=color.new(rColor, lTransp))
    line.delete(_h[1])
    _l = line.new(start, orbL, end, orbL, xloc.bar_time, color=color.new(sColor, lTransp))
    line.delete(_l[1])
    if showAvg
        _a = line.new(start, orbA, end, orbA, xloc.bar_time, color=color.new(aColor, lTransp))
        line.delete(_a[1])

// Plot labels
if isToday
    l_h = label.new(start, orbH, text="High", xloc=xloc.bar_time, textcolor=rColor, style=label.style_none)
    label.delete(l_h[1])
    l_l = label.new(start, orbL, text="Low", xloc=xloc.bar_time, textcolor=sColor, style=label.style_none)
    label.delete(l_l[1])
    if showAvg
        l_a = label.new(start, orbA, text="Avg", xloc=xloc.bar_time, textcolor=aColor, style=label.style_none)
        label.delete(l_a[1])


plot(showHistoricalORB ? orbH : na, title=' High', color=rColor, transp=lTransp)
plot(showHistoricalORB ? orbL : na, title=' Low', color=sColor, transp=lTransp)
plot(showHistoricalORB ? showAvg ? orbA : na : na, title=' Avg', color=aColor, transp=lTransp)


// Display Buy & Sell signal
plotSignals = false
if showHistoricalORB
    plotSignals := true
else
    if year(time) == year(timenow) and month(timenow) == month(time) and dayofmonth(time) == dayofmonth(timenow) 
        plotSignals := true


// Determine if long/short can occur. After one has occurred, no others will be issued until next session.
goLong = false
goShort = false
if bars234InRange and close > orbH
    goLong := true
    bars234InRange := false
else
    if bars234InRange and close < orbL
        goShort := true
        bars234InRange := false

plotshape(plotSignals and goLong ? crossover(close, orbH) : na, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.lime, text="Buy", textcolor=color.lime)
plotshape(plotSignals and goShort ? crossover(orbL, close) : na, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, text="Sell", textcolor=color.red)

// Debugging plots
plotchar(barNo, "barNo", "", location.top)
plotchar(bars234InRange, "bars234InRange", "•", location.top)
plotchar(goLong, "goLong", "▲", location.top)
plotchar(goShort, "goShort", "▼", location.top)
plotchar(time("D", "0915-1530"), 'time("D", "0915-1530")', "", location.top)
plotchar(newbar, "newbar", "►", location.top)
```

[image]